# setting a property of a control using a property of other control in WPF

Tags: wpf-controls, binding

I have a border inside that I have a text box.

I want to set a property of border based on the property of textbox. I want to accomplish this without using ElementName... Is this possible? Please help me out.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ElementName`?

Answer (score 0):

I think using ElementName is the only way to databind the border to the TextBox's text.
The other way to get the interaction it is to handle the TextChanged event. Inside the handler you can interpret the value of the TextBox and apply it to the border.